# Stop scroll on click on anchor in a tab navigation in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to stop the window from scrolling when an anchor is clicked or opened?
http://domainsoutlook.com/s/site/stackoverflow.com.html#meta_info
Try some other tabs and the window scrolls down.

Also, could it be possible to reload the whole page when an anchor/tab is clicked/changed?

Comment: you have two conflicting requirements here... do you want it to stop scrolling or for the page to reload?

Comment: I want it to stop scrolling and the page to reload as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a return false;

```
<a href="#seo_report" onclick="return false;">SEO Report</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must return false after call to function switching tabs (onclick="function();return false") or at the end of that function.